# Spring Batch- Read the .csv file and write the records to a txt file

Tags: spring-batch

I want to read from a .csv file and write the records in .csv file to a .txt file. Text file should have only those records which have string "900" in csv file . Below is few of the records present in the .csv file.

```
COAR10|900|AR10|ARGENTINA||163222|14-AUG|ARS|L|19908.60 
COAR11|900|AR10| ARGENTINA||163222|14-AUG|ARS|L|19908.60 
COAR12|901|AR10| ARGENTINA||163222|14-AUG|ARS|L|19908.60
```

Comment: Show us some effort by trying some code yourself first. **Hint** read `HELP FOR` and `HELP IF`. Then, if you run into an specific problem, post back in SO. We will be happy to help you... but we will not do your work for you.

Comment: Apologies...I can write code to read the .csv file with the pipe delimiter , what help I need is to select the records with string "900"  . Also, I would like to add the number of records would be around 200000 in the .csv file.

Comment: Can you edit your question with everything you said in the comment and adding also your job configuration? One answer is an [ItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemProcessor.html) that checks the **900** but I'm not sure about the number of records , It would be a walk in the park if you use a custom writer but again I have no idea about your configuration

Comment: `findstr "|900|" input.csv > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I used `test.csv` for my test :

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.csv) do (
  for /f  "tokens=2 delims=|" %%b in ('echo "%%a"') do if %%b==900 echo %%a))>output.txt
```

The output in `output.txt` :

```
COAR10|900|AR10|ARGENTINA||163222|14-AUG|ARS|L|19908.60 
COAR11|900|AR10| ARGENTINA||163222|14-AUG|ARS|L|19908.60
```